# Pandas how to calculate bygroup result based on the length of the each group and a count value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the scoring rate of each zone by using bygroup in pandas, but not sure how to do it:

Suppose the df has two columns as:

```
Shot_type   Shot_zone
   Goal     Penalty_area
   Saved    Penalty_area
   Goal     Goal Box
   Saved    Goal Box
```

Here I want to groupy by Shot_zone, and calculate the scoring rate based on Shot_type's Goal counts / len() of each type Shot_zone. Here each Shot_zone has 1 goal and 1 saved, so the result should be like:

```
Penalty_area   50%
Goal Box       50%
```

Is there any understandable approach to do so using Pandas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also `groupby` and `apply`

```
df.groupby('Shot_zone').Shot_type.apply(lambda s: '{}%'.format((s[s=='Goal']).size/(s.size) * 100))

Shot_zone
Goal_Box        50.0%
Penalty_area    50.0%
```

Comment: Actually your answer is more accurate...I don't know why crosstab doesn't give me the correct result, maybe it is cumulative?

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
pd.crosstab(df.Shot_type,df.Shot_zone,normalize='index')
Out[662]: 
Shot_zone  GoalBox  Penalty_area
Shot_type                       
Goal           0.5           0.5
Saved          0.5           0.5
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, this gets me more than what I want!

Comment: @commentallez-vous you can always using .loc for select the index you need

Comment: Got it. I know both iloc and loc, but not sure how to work on the bygroup object...I am just learning by using it, but totally new to pandas

Answer (score 1):

One way is to binarize your `Shot_type` column, i.e. set to `True` if it equals `'Goal'`, and then use `GroupBy` + `mean`:

```
res = df.assign(Shot_type=df['Shot_type']=='Goal')\
        .groupby('Shot_zone')['Shot_type'].mean()

print(res)

Shot_zone
GoalBox         0.5
Penalty_area    0.5
Name: Shot_type, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you jpp, great answer, though I actually had 4 different Shot_type haha

Comment: @commentallez-vous, Ah, then use `crosstab` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using following:

```
data[data['Shot_type']=='Goal'].groupby(['Shot_zone'])['Shot_zone'].count()
/data.groupby(['Shot_zone'])['Shot_zone'].count())
```